# Html вывод на экран

Tags: html

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить вопрос...
Хочу что бы в таблице я ввёл текст и при нажатии кнопки "+" этот текст переносился в нижнюю таблицу.
В комментария я указал куда нужно перенести.

```
    <div class="Oddo-header">
        <button class="Oddo-button Oddo-button-add" id="Oddo-button-add" >+</button> \\ ПРИ НАЖАТИИ ЭТОЙ КНОПКИ, Я ХОЧУ ЧТО БЫ ВВЕДЁННЫЙ МНОЙ ТЕКСТ ПОЯВИЛСЯ В НИЖНЕЙ ТАБЛИЦЕ.
    </div>
    <div class="Oddo-list">
        <div class="Oddo-card" id="card-1">
            <label class="label">Content</label>
            <input class="content" type="text" /> \\ ЗДЕСЬ Я ВВОЖУ ТЕКСТ!
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="Oddo">
        <div class="Oddo-canvas">

            <div class="Oddo-header">
            </div>
            <div class="Oddo-list">

                \\ ВОТ ЗДЕСЬ ОН ДОЛЖЕН ПОЯВИТСЯ. ПОМОГИТЕ РЕШИТЬ ПОЖАЛУЙСТА.
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: На HTML - никак :) Нужен JavaScript — https://learn.javascript.ru/

Comment: понял, спасибо.